# FitNesse test: get count of DOM nodes

Tags: fitnesse

I am new to FitNesse and I am trying to figure out how to write a test that counts the number of children of a given DOM element, and then tests for that number. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What web testing library are you using?  SeleNesse?  SpiderFixture?  Something else?  FitNesse itself doesn't do that.  You need a fixture that uses Selenium or Sahi or some other web testing library to get to the DOM.

Comment: We are using Selenium, thanks. We could do this using Javascript eval,  I think, but I thought there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

How are you integrating FitNesse and Selenium? Via direct WebDriver calls in your fixtures?

If you are using your own WebDriver implementation (or any other method that allows you to work directly with WebElement objects) you could query the WebElement by selecting all child nodes and counting those:

```
public int countTotalChildElementsForElement(final WebElement domElement) {
    return domElement.findElements(By.xpath("//*")).size();
}
```